# "Cannot find proj.db" in PostgreSQL+PostGIS logs

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Just had a look at my (long neglected) PostgreSQL logs and found a *ton* of these errors:

```
pj_obj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create: no database context specified
proj_create: Cannot find proj.db
proj_create_operation_factory_context: Cannot find proj.db
```

All I found was references to GDAL and (py)proj though, which confuses me. I.e. as far as I understand those are libraries used in clients, not as part of PostGIS/PostgreSQL. Also the db seems to work just fine, which seems unexpected to me if a seemingly important dependency would fail.

So yeah I don't get it. Can anyone give me some insights into what the heck is going on?

E: proper system specs:

- OpenSUSE 15.2
- PostgreSQL 12.5
- PostGIS 3.0.3
- Installed via zypper from Application_Geo repo

E2: more infos:

- Output of `select postgis_full_version()`: `"POSTGIS="3.0.3 6660953" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2" PROJ="7.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.7" LIBJSON="0.13" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2""`
- No `PROJ_LIB` variable set
- `find / -name proj.db` does not yield results

- running `SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 4326) FROM some_Table;` works without issues. (`geom` being verified SRID 3857)

Comment: Is this on Windows, or Linux? What distro? How did you install?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto will update

Comment: PostGIS requires the Proj coordinate transformation library https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html. The documentation mentions Proj4 but the newest Proj version is 8. The error that you get means that your PostGIS is built with Proj version >= 6. Proj tries to find an SQLite database "proj.db" where all the transformation parameters are stored. Database is not found > Proj fails > PostGIS fails.

Comment: @user30184 except postgis does not seem to fail, all functionality work as expected as far as I can tell. Also I would expect the package manager to take care and looking at the output of `zypper search -s libproj` it also did (libproj19 is marked as being installed).

Comment: Without knowing where proj.db is it should fail if you try to use ST_Transform. What Proj version is listed by `select postgis_full_version()`? Do you have the environmental variable PROJ_LIB set? Can you find proj.db from that directory?

Comment: @user30184 updated my post with your inputs and a bunch of other things ... yep its a weird one. If my DB just wouldn't work it would make sense but based on all indications I have it does.
PS: either way, I'll replicate the exact setup now on a test setup (current main test env is still ubuntu based, where I'm not getting this error)

Answer (score 2):

Well, figured it out, and it was embarrassingly simple. I just really got confused by the db still working as it should. The thing that was missing was quite literally a `zypper in proj`. Not even a postgres restart required.

Guess I'll file a bug report with the package maintainer (if I can find them) to add this as a dependency in future releases.